# Stop hover effect after click

Tags: jquery

I have a pretty simple problem in jQuery, and I can't seem to find a solution:
I have a mouseOver and mouseOut effect, but I need a twist, if click than keep that box open even though their is a mouseOut.

Here's an example of what I have so far :

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grmej/1/)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(".rock").click(function() {
      $('.rock').unbind('mouseout');
});
```

Unbind the mouseout event at .rock click.

Answer (score 1):

You have to unbind the events, then it stays open forever.

[Made you an updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Grmej/5/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".rock").click(function() {
     $(this).off('mouseout');
```

If you have multiple mouseOut events you may wish to namespace them and remove just the one in question  (the above code removes all mouseOut events bound to the `.rock` element).

Answer (score -1):

Try this insted

```
    $(".rock").hover(function() {
    $(".box_content.rock").stop().animate(
          {"height": "100px"},
          "normal");
    $(".box.rock").stop().animate(
          {"height": "140px"},
          "normal");
    $(".hide.rock").removeClass("hide").addClass("show");
    })

    $('.box_content.rock').click(function(){    
    $('.box_content.rock').unbind("hover");
    });
```

Comment: `$('.box_content.rock').unbind("hover");` do not work very well